# App has been deleting for ever

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, delete

I tried to install Steam, but it failed. The thing is, I tried to delete it from the app center (not sure what it is called in English), but it has been stuck at the 'Deleting...' point for last 20 mins. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then using `sudo apt-get purge steam`. The other option is to try restarting the system and then deleting it from the Software Center again.

Comment: Tried, then it said: E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Are there any other programs open besides terminal?

Comment: Completed delete by restarting system. Thanks! (= Btw no there aren't.

Comment: Glad I could help! Your error was probably that the program had actually deleted, but Software Center wasn't being told that it had been finished. If there had been any other porgrams open that would have been using the admin directory, then the system blocks purges so it doesn't screw up the other programs as well.